# Does centripetal force being equal to full tension dependent on if string is horizontal or vertical?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, string, centripetal-force

If the string is not horizontal, is the centripetal force still equal to the full tension in the string and equivalently to the weight of the objects? If not equal, is the centripetal force bigger or smaller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Centripetal force]

Firstly, the string **cannot** be horizontal, unless something supports the object.

Secondly, *the centripetal force is not equal to the full tension in the string*. The centripetal force acts in the horizontal plane the object travels in.

The forces:

$$T\cos\alpha=F_c$$
$$T\sin\alpha=mg$$
So that:

$$\frac{mg}{F_c}=\tan\alpha$$

where $F_c=mr\omega^2$. You can see why $\alpha=0$ is not possible: it requires $\omega \to +\infty$!

So the centripetal force is proportional to the **mass** of the object.

Comment: Thank you so much! I kinda now have a better understanding

Comment: You're welcome.